# Idiomatic Go to precisely read N lines (and not a byte over) of text?

Tags: csv, go

I have a CSV from a report generator that adds some non-CSV preamble, like:

```
Time Off Requests

My Org
Street Address
City, State  ZIP

Col1,Col2,Col3
r1c1,r1c2,r1c3
r2c1,r2c2,r2c3
```

I need to discard the 6 lines before passing the file's io.Reader to csv.NewReader and trying a ReadAll(), so I need to ensure I don't read even a byte past the 6th line.

I originally thought of bufio.Scanner and calling Scan() in a loop 6 times, but then experimentally realized the "buf" in bufio means I cannot control where the buffered reads end and it will likely read past the true start of the CSV.

So I came up with just reading byte-by-byte till I've counted six line feeds (10):

```golang
f, _ := os.Open(csvPath)

// Read just past report-generated 6-line preamble
b := make([]byte, 1)
for i := 0; i < 6; {
    f.Read(b)
    if b[0] == 10 {
        i++
    }
}

r := csv.NewReader(f)
records, err = r.ReadAll()
...
```

And that works.  But, is there a more idiomatic Go way?

Comment: If you want to read byte-by-byte, there is already a [`ReadByte`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader.ReadByte) implementation

Comment: @JimB, that appears to have the same drawback as the Scanner, bufio does buffered reads of the file past the true start of the CSV.

Comment: I don't think this is about "idiomatic": If you don't want to read more than up to a certain (the sixth \n) byte and not any more you either have to read byte by byte or "undo" excess reads. "Idiomatic" unreading via bufio.Reader.UnreadByte works for a single byte so it doesn't make much sense. Don't overcomplicate the working solution.

Comment: @ZachYoung, What does it matter if the the reader buffers past the preamble? You should almost always be using buffered reads anyway.

Comment: @Volker, thank you for that perspective. I still consider myself new to low-level file reading and Go... just making sure I didn't miss something straightforward the standard lib provides.

Comment: @JimB, I need to stop at the true start of the CSV data so the csv.Reader can pick up where the preamble-deleter left off... otherwise I read "into" the CSV and that breaks the csv.Reader.

Comment: You pass the same reader to `csv.NewReader` and don't throw away the buffered data. The file position doesn't matter.

Comment: @JimB, my understanding and experimentation shows the buffered readers affect the underlying file's io.Reader, if I do anything with a buffered reader then do a simple `f.Read(b)` and inspect the contents of `b` I can see the file's Reader has overshot the 7th line. The "file position" matters when trying to parse CSV... the csv.Reader has to be at the start of the CSV data.

Comment: Once you use use a buffered reader you should not directly access the original reader again (unless you want to reset the position based on the buffered data). This how any use of buffered io in every language works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255957/discussion-between-zach-young-and-jimb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to avoid using `bufio`, in fact you should prefer using buffered IO when possible. What you can't do is use the original reader *after* accessing it through the `bufio.Reader`, i,e, don't pass the `os.File` to `csv.NewReader` after using `bufio.NewReader`, continue using the `bufio.Reader` which may contain data already read from the file.

Once you have a `bufio.Reader`, you can make use of all the methods for reading parts of the stream, and don't need to worry about reading byte-by-byte.

```
buf := bufio.NewReader(f)
// the preambled is defined as 6 lines
for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
    line, err := buf.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("line: %q\n", line)
}
r := csv.NewReader(buf)
records, err := r.ReadAll()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("records: %q\n", records)
```

[Full Example](https://go.dev/play/p/xflKPIPwhWx)